# Let $s_n=\sum_l (e^{ix} − 1)^{-1}(e^{inx} − e^{-i(n-1)x})$ where $x=c+l\omega$ . How to show that $s_1+...+s_n=\sum_l \frac{1-\cos nx}{1-\cos x }?$

Tags: calculus, summation

If i define $s_n=\sum_l (e^{i(c+l\cdot \omega)} − 1)^{-1}(e^{in(c+l\cdot \omega)} − e^{-i(n-1)(c+l \cdot \omega)})$ where $c \in [0,2\pi]$, how can i show that $$s_1+s_2+...+s_n=\sum_l \frac{1-\cos n(c+l\cdot \omega)}{1-\cos(c+l\cdot \omega) }?$$
I think it is just a calculation but i can not find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Invert the order of summation between $n$ and $l$.